# Jrebele + JBoss 4.2.3. How to set the launching from run.bat

Tags: java, jboss, jrebel

I would like to know what to change in debug.bat (or in any other configuration file) in order to use JRebel from console rather than from IDE. 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You basically need to add `-javaagent:[path/to/]jrebel.jar` to `JAVA_OPTS`

[Documentation](http://manuals.zeroturnaround.com/jrebel/standalone/launch-from-command-line.html#jboss-4-x-5-x-6-x)